# Is it possible to migrate Memcached data to Redis?

Tags: redis, memcached, data-migration

I have searched Google and SO and surprisingly haven't been able to find a very good answer to this.  Is there any sort of method or best practice for migrating data from a Memcached cluster into a Redis cluster? Are there are any tools or tricks to help with this process?

If it's not possible, is there any recommendation for how to handle this kind of scenario? I assume that pointing to a new cache that hasn't been pre-warmed will cause some application slowness, I'm just wondering if there are any workaround for this, assuming a migration of the Memcache data isn't possible.